# Get object from array by index, that is getting from another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

There are two arrays: idArrayInt and nameArrayString. I need to get an object from first array by index, that I get from second. I know that it is pretty simple, but I'm new at IOS development and don't understand how to implement it.

```
var idArray = [Int]() //for example 1 2 3
var nameArray = [String]() // for example "one" "two" "three"
var ident: Int!

@IBAction func btnNext_click(_ sender: AnyObject) {

var nameString = lblUnitType.text
var index = nameArray.index(of: nameString) //Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: String?)' 
ident = idArray[index] //something like that by I don't sure     
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you would be better off using a dictionary than an array

Comment: or an array of a custom struct, containing just the ID and name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lblUnitType.text` and the result of `index(of:` are optionals, you need to unwrap them preferable with optional bindings:

```
if let nameString = lblUnitType.text, let index = nameArray.index(of: nameString), index < idArray.count { 
    ident = idArray[index] 
}
```

Comment: @NiravD Thanks, I added a *where* clause

Answer (score 1):

You can learn in this playground as shown.
[image]

Also, in your case you can refer dictionaries.
[image]